# How to check if one of my checkbox in checkboxlist is checked?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, checkbox, checkboxlist

I know this might be something that a lot of people has been asking. Here's my problem, I found this method through online, but the problem is my `count2` doesn't add on. Only `count` add on. I have a horizontal checkboxlist and I have two checkbox inside, Nurse care and meal plan.

```
 int count = 0;
            int count2 = 0;

                if (CheckBoxList1.Items[0].Selected)
                {
                    count++;
                }
                else if (CheckBoxList1.Items[1].Selected)
                {
                    count2++;
                }
```

Comment: Isn't this normal? Your either `if` part work or `else if` works if condition is true? Did you debug your code and see what happens?

Comment: Oh yes, thats it that else if.. What a mistake.. Didn't realize that..